# error: PostgreSQL/15/lib/timescaledb-2.9.3.dll Unable to load library The specified module could not be found

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

i have problem when i install timescaledb.

i installed postgresql-15.2-1-windows-x64, timescaledb-postgresql-15_latest-windows-amd64.

i followed install manual.

but i have error message which is '오류:  "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/15/lib/timescaledb-2.9.3.dll" 라이브러리를 불러 올 수 없음: The specified module could not be found.' when i write 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb;' on postgres cmd.

how can i fix it?

i tried that move files(ssleay32.dll , libeay32.dll) to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin folder.
but i have same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please, check if the configuration parameter `shared_preload_libraries` is in the postgresql.conf file and it matches the TimescaleDB .dll folder.

If the dll is not located there, you may need to move the library to the correct directory or update the configuration file to reflect the correct path.

Have you checked any different errors in the server logs?

Also, the troubleshooting doc can be useful: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Extension_build_troubleshooting

and a recent question on timescaledb forum: https://www.timescale.com/forum/t/how-to-install-timescale-db-on-window/1274